# AWS Elastic Beanstalk SpringBoot fat WAR : jsp not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

in my application.properties. I create a standalone war with `gradle bootWar`. The jsp files get resolved fine when running locally, but on eb the jsp files cannot be found and it ends with a 404. I'm using a simple eb amz linux 2 environment.

Of note is how eb runs the file: `java -jar application.**jar**` instead of `java -jar application.**war**`.

My question is:

1. Will running it as a WAR solve the problem and how do I make eb run it as a WAR?
2. If the ans. to #1 is to use a non-standalone WAR on a eb tomcat environment, what options do I have to make it use ssl? The standalone WAR configures ssl with application properties. Will that continue to work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Spring Boot app with Thymeleaf and never seen an issue of not finding the view in the templates folder. See this AWS tutorial that builds a basic Spring Boot app that invokes AWS services and deploys it to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

By the way, this app is deployed as a JAR:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project

Comment: Yes thymeleaf works with jar packages but afaik jsp doesn't. This is because of package structure but I do not completely understand the underlying reason.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with war packaging and deploying it in a eb tomcat environment. SSL is now handled by the nginx reverse proxy instead of the app server.

Here's my nginx proxy config in case it's useful:

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32714;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen       443 default ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        error_page  497 https://$host$request_uri;

        ssl_certificate      <full-path-to-fullchain.pem>;
        ssl_certificate_key  <full-path-to-privkey.pem>;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
          rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        client_header_timeout 60;
    client_max_body_size  10M;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;

    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```